# Postgresql - Update all values of table after sorting it

Tags: postgresql, sorting, sql-update

In my database, I have my records as follows:

```
Start_date | Product_code
2009-01-01 | 1
2010-01-01 | 1
...
...
```

I want to update the start_date to be start_date + 1.
But I have (Start_date, product_code) as my primary key.
If I execute my query as

```
update products set start_date = start_date + '1 year'::interval ;
```

This returns an error saying that another entry already exists (because 2010-01-01, 1 is already a entry in the table).
Basically, I need to update after sorting the entries in descending order by start_date.
I can do by creating another table with the same schema, copying all entries in sorted manner to the temporary table, truncating the original table and then populating entries in this table after adding the start_date.
Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Postgres 9.0 you can define the primary key to be deferrable. That means it will only be checked when you commit your transaction, not for each row.

```
create table products
(
  start_date date not null,
  product_code integer not null,
  primary key (start_date, product_code) deferrable
);

insert into products
values
(date '2009-01-01', 1),
(date '2010-01-01', 1),
(date '2011-01-01', 1),
(date '2012-01-01', 1);


update products
  set start_date = start_date + interval '1' year;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/19b56/1

Answer (score 0):

Add to your table another date column what doubles your start_date entries. With trigger you can synchronize both. If you need a special column name for reading, you can add a view that represents the original layout.

In this case you got a fixed primary date column, but you work (reading, updates) with another one.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange behaviour for me (I'm usually work with SQL Server). Here's an article that could be helpful for you - [PostgreSQL: UPDATE a table using ORDER BY](http://www.pelagodesign.com/blog/2007/07/23/postgresql-update-a-table-using-order-by/). It's from 2007, so may be there's some more elegant solution. Solution based on this article (not that I like it very much):

```
create view vw_products as select start_date from products order by start_date desc;

create rule vw_products_update as on update to vw_products
do instead update products set start_date = new.start_date where start_date = old.start_date;

update vw_products set start_date = start_date + '1 year'::interval;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fd6c3/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

how about a quick way (just for this example, assuming that your dates are near to now)

```
update products set start_date = start_date + '50 year'::interval ;
update products set start_date = start_date - '49 year'::interval ;
```

i think this will not produce duplicate key errors

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function update_order_by () RETURNS VOID as $$

DECLARE i RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN  SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY start_date DESC LOOP

         UPDATE product SET start_date = i.start_date + '1 year'::interval  WHERE start_date = i.start_date;

    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```